# If conditions and copying values from different rows

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following data:

```
Data <- data.frame(Project=c(123,123,123,123,123,123,124,124,124,124,124,125,125,125),
               Name=c("Harry","David","David","Harry","Peter","Peter","John","Alex","Alex","Mary","Mary","Dan","Joe","Joe"),
                      Value=c(1,4,7,3,8,9,8,3,2,5,6,2,2,1),
                      OldValue=c("","Open","In Progress","Complete","Open","In Progress","Complete","Open","In Progress","System Declined","In Progress","","Open","In Progress"),
                      NewValue=c("Open","In Progress","Complete","Open","In Progress","Complete","Open","In Progress","System Declined","In Progress","Complete","Open","In Progress","Complete"))
```

[The data should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MtPK.png)

I want to create another column called EditedBy that applies the following logic.

1. IF the project in row 1 equals the project in row 2 AND the New Value in row 1 equals "Open"  THEN take the name from row 2. If either of the first two conditions are False, then stick with the name in the first row.

[So the data should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ8zQ.png)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data)[, EditedBy := Name[2L] ,.(Project, grp=cumsum(NewValue == "Open"|
                         shift(NewValue == "System Declined", fill=TRUE)))]

Data
# Project  Name Value        OldValue        NewValue EditedBy
# 1:     123 Harry     1                            Open    David
# 2:     123 David     4            Open     In Progress    David
# 3:     123 David     7     In Progress        Complete    David
# 4:     123 Harry     3        Complete            Open    Peter
# 5:     123 Peter     8            Open     In Progress    Peter
# 6:     123 Peter     9     In Progress        Complete    Peter
# 7:     124  John     8        Complete            Open     Alex
# 8:     124  Alex     3            Open     In Progress     Alex
# 9:     124  Alex     2     In Progress System Declined     Alex
#10:     124  Mary     5 System Declined     In Progress     Mary
#11:     124  Mary     6     In Progress        Complete     Mary
#12:     125   Dan     2                            Open      Joe
#13:     125   Joe     2            Open     In Progress      Joe
#14:     125   Joe     1     In Progress        Complete      Joe
```